# Get all viewholders recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I need to get the position of all the `viewholders` in my `recyclerview`. Basically, when the user clicks a button, if any edit text fields are blank, the user cannot proceed. I am also setting each edit text through a setter in a class. This is so that I can remove the underline for all of the edit texts and basically make it not editable.

This is my onbindviewholder

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position){


    /*
    Holder for exercise row
    Sets the text for exercise, weight, sets, and reps
    Disables text if save button is clicked
     */
    if(holder instanceof ExerciseRowHolder) {

        int pos = holder.getAdapterPosition();
        Log.d("pos", String.format("%s", pos));
        ((ExerciseModel) rowTypeList.get(pos)).setExerciseEditText(((ExerciseRowHolder) holder).exercise);
        ((ExerciseModel) rowTypeList.get(pos)).setWeightEditText(((ExerciseRowHolder) holder).weight);
        ((ExerciseModel) rowTypeList.get(pos)).setSetsEditText(((ExerciseRowHolder) holder).set);
        ((ExerciseModel) rowTypeList.get(pos)).setRepsEditText(((ExerciseRowHolder) holder).rep);
        ((ExerciseModel) rowTypeList.get(pos)).setDragHandle(((ExerciseRowHolder) holder).dragHandle);
        ((ExerciseModel) rowTypeList.get(pos)).setExerciseRowTextWatcher(((ExerciseRowHolder) holder).exerciseRowTextWatcher);
        ((ExerciseRowHolder) holder).updatePosition(pos);
```

This is when a user clicks that button. The issue with this is that the edit texts will return null for `viewholders` outside of the screen because the edit texts are being set in `onbindviewholder`, which means only the edit texts on the screen are being set. I need all of the edit texts to be set. Any suggestions on getting all the `viewholders` of a `recyclerview`?

```
        int childCount = displayWorkoutAdapter.getItemCount() - 1;
    //checks for all the children of recyclerView excluding the buttons
    for (int a = childCount; a > 0; a--) {
        RowType rowType = displayWorkoutAdapter.rowTypeList.get(a);

        //if the first row = exercise row, check to see if there is any input in the exercise, sets, and reps field
        //if not, display error
        if (rowType.getClass() == ExerciseModel.class) {
            AutoCompleteTextView exercise = ((ExerciseModel) rowType).getExerciseEditText();
            EditText weight = ((ExerciseModel) rowType).getWeightEditText();
            EditText sets = ((ExerciseModel) rowType).getSetsEditText();
            EditText reps = ((ExerciseModel) rowType).getRepsEditText();

            /*
            if(exercise == null){
                exercise = exerciseRow.findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView);
                weight = exerciseRow.findViewById(R.id.weight);
                sets = exerciseRow.findViewById(R.id.sets);
                reps = exerciseRow.findViewById(R.id.reps);
            }*/


            textListenerToRemoveError(exercise, weight, sets, reps);
```

Answer (score 0):

The point of `RecyclerView` is that it doesn't hold all the items at the same time as it slows down the performance and loads only the items that you can see on the screen. It's the modern approach, but if you want to load all items at once there is `ListView` class ([docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html)) It displays a vertically-scrollable collection of views, where each view is positioned immediately below the previous view in the list.

So your items will be loaded at once but it's not considered up to date.

Comment: I'd prefer to stick with the RecyclerView since I already have everything implemented for it. The only issue I have is making all the edit texts non editable. I know I could set a flag in the onbindviewholder, for whenever that button is clicked, disable the edit text. However, I am unsure of how to check that all edit texts are filled in